# I am unable to find the solution for this code these are the questions

Tags: javascript, json, function

- Write a function to take pokemon’s name as argument and display the
  information of that pokemon
- Write a function that takes pokemon’s name as an argument and find out
  which all pokemon have that name in their “next_evolution” field.
- Write a function that take a “Weakness” as an input and gives the names
  of all pokemon who have that Weakness. (check the weakness array in
  the dataset).

it doesnt show any error nor not finding the solution ... i need help in solving this,i am a beginner so the detailed logic or code would be helpful

```js
var goPokemon = {
  "pokemon": [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "num": "003",
    "name": "Venusaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/003.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "2.01 m",
    "weight": "100.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.017,
    "avg_spawns": 1.7,
    "spawn_time": "11:30",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }, {
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }]
  }]
}


var DetailOfPokemon = function(name, goPokemon) {

  for (var x in goPokemon.pokemon) {
    if (goPokemon.pokemon[x].name == findname) {
      var Detail = goPokemon.pokemon[x];
      alert(Detail);
    } else {}
  }

  var findname = window.prompt('Enter the name of Pokemon')

};
DetailOfPokemon(name, goPokemon)
```

Comment: @VicJordan Asking about homeworks is on-topic at SO, as long as something has been tried, and the problem is described. That seems to be the case in this post.

Comment: The title of the question is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var findname = window.prompt('Enter the name of Pokemon')` is badly placed. You compare `goPokemon.pokemon[x].name` with `findname` and `findname` isn't yet defined.

The function [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will convert an object into a json string (might be easier to display the informations).

By the way, if you don't need an `else` instruction, don't write it.

```js
var goPokemon = {
  "pokemon": [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "num": "003",
    "name": "Venusaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/003.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "2.01 m",
    "weight": "100.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.017,
    "avg_spawns": 1.7,
    "spawn_time": "11:30",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }, {
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }]
  }]
}






var DetailOfPokemon = function(findname, goPokemon) {
    for (var x in goPokemon.pokemon) 
    { 
        if (goPokemon.pokemon[x].name == findname)
        {
            var Detail = goPokemon.pokemon[x];
            alert(JSON.stringify(Detail, null, 4));
        }
    }  
};
var name = window.prompt('Enter the name of Pokemon')
DetailOfPokemon(name, goPokemon)
```